# My left arm is much much stronger than my right!

Tags: weights, biceps

I've been going to the gym for about three weeks now. For the first two bicep workouts I did 2.5kgs,for my third I tried with 5 but I couldn't even get my right arm to lift up just a little. However I could easily do a few reps on my left. How do I balance out? Also, when should I ideally be adding weights to my bicep workout?

Comment: bicep workout? wtf dude? do you workout one muscle at a time? just do sensible stuff that uses your whole body at a time, strength will follow.

Answer (score 0):

**Rectifying imbalances** is not something you do by working the weaker side more than the other, as suggested in another answer.

Consider your scenario. You might have a stronger left-side bicep than right-side. However, if you were to do more curls on the right side, you're also training the right-side forearm and shoulder. You're also training the left-side core muscles because they will be doing more counter-balancing work since you place more weight (or doing more reps) on the right side. In other words, you're substituting one imbalance, for a plethora of new ones.

The most surefire way to balance out unequalities, is by simply training them equally.

As for your bicep workout progression, it's hard to say without knowing anything about your workout. But then again, bicep curls are an isolation exercise. You might be better off doing it at the end of an upper back workout (which engages biceps a lot) for the added bicep hypertrophy.